# Change a DataGridView Image column cells layout to zoom

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

One of the tables whose data is loaded using the function below has an image field (BLOB) which appears correctly on the DataGridView but I would like to make that column cells layout zoom. I've tried this but doesnt work:

```
For Each column As DataGridViewImageColumn _
    In dgvAtivado.Columns
        column.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
Next
```

I'm filling the DataGridView using this function:

```
Public Sub show(dgv As DataGridView, ByRef connection As MySqlConnection, ByVal table_name As String, ByVal primary_key As String, ByVal query As String) 
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Try
        adapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand
        adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection

        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = query

        ds.Clear()
        connection.Open()
        adapter.Fill(ds, table_name)
        connection.Close()

        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dgv.DataSource = ds
        dgv.DataMember = table_name 
        dgv.Columns.Item(primary_key).Visible = False
        dgv.ClearSelection()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Th error is It's not possible to associate the object which type is 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to the type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn'.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking this it's because the image are too big to fit those small cells